# is there a relation between video and audio

Tags: image-processing, audio-processing

"I would like to extract 'n' frames and obtain the corresponding spectrogram for those frames. I'm unsure if there is a specific duration, such as 20 frames equating to 15 milliseconds or something similar, that should be considered for this process."

Comment: Video has it's frame rate and audio has it's sample rate. If you are lucky there is a nice integer relationship. For example if you video is at 120 fps and the audio is at 48 kHz, you have 400 audio samples per video frame. The exact values depends on the format of your specific file.

Comment: is there a formula for relation

Comment: Audio sample rate divided by video frame rate. 48000sample/sec/(120 frames/sec) = 400 samples/frame.

Comment: thank you so much